# How to substract one column value to another column value as per Particular ID

Tags: sql

My Query is

```
select c.Date, d.PartyName, e.ItemName, a.InwardNo, b.Quantity as [Inward Quantity],    ISNULL(c.Quantity, 0) as [Outward Quantity],
(ISNULL(b.Quantity, 0) - ISNULL(SUM(c.Quantity), 0)) as [Balance Quantity], e.Weight
from tblInwardParty a
Left Join tblInwardItems b ON a.InwardNo = b.InwardNo
Left Join tblOutwardItem c ON a.PartyCode = c.PartyCode and b.ItemCode = c.ItemCode and     a.InwardNo = c.InwardNo
Join tblPartyMaster d ON a.PartyCode = d.PartyCode
Join tblItemMaster e ON b.ItemCode = e.ItemCode
where a.InwardNo = 19778
Group By a.InwardNo, PartyName, ItemName, c.Date, Weight, b.Quantity, c.Quantity
Order By PartyName
```

My Output is

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Date             Party Name      Item Name   Inward No     Inward Qua     Outward Qua             Balance Qua       Weight
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    -----------------------------
06/05/13    A R ENTERPRISE  SODA ASH IMP    19778       400     17       383        50
07/10/13    A R ENTERPRISE  SODA ASH IMP    19778       400     100         300     50
10/11/13    A R ENTERPRISE  SODA ASH IMP    19778       400     1          399      50
13/06/13    A R ENTERPRISE  SODA ASH IMP    19778       400     20         380      50
22/06/13    A R ENTERPRISE  SODA ASH IMP    19778       400     200         200     50
22/07/13    A R ENTERPRISE  SODA ASH IMP    19778       400     30         370      50
27/06/13    A R ENTERPRISE  SODA ASH IMP    19778       400     20          380     50
28/06/13    A R ENTERPRISE  SODA ASH IMP    19778       400     10          390     50
```

---

so my query is that when i substract 400 - 17 it give as 383 result it is fine on first time but second time it again taking 
400 - 100 and giving balance as 300 which i don't want, I just want to take previous balance as actual balance and substract curent value as per same Party_Name and same Item_Name

As Like that

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    -----------------------------
Date             Party Name      Item Name   Inward No     Inward Qua     Outward Qua         Balance Qua       Weight
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    -----------------------------
06/05/13    A R ENTERPRISE  SODA ASH IMP    19778       400     17          383     50
07/10/13    A R ENTERPRISE  SODA ASH IMP    19778       400     100         283     50
10/11/13    A R ENTERPRISE  SODA ASH IMP    19778       400     1          282      50
13/06/13    A R ENTERPRISE  SODA ASH IMP    19778       400     20         262      50
22/06/13    A R ENTERPRISE  SODA ASH IMP    19778       400     200         62      50
22/07/13    A R ENTERPRISE  SODA ASH IMP    19778       400     30          32      50
27/06/13    A R ENTERPRISE  SODA ASH IMP    19778       400     20          12      50
28/06/13    A R ENTERPRISE  SODA ASH IMP    19778       400     10        2     50
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: I think you are asking about a running total?  What DB are you on?

Comment: This does seem like you want a [running total](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Running_total). Plenty of questions on the subject have been asked on this site alone, and I'm sure there's also much information elsewhere. Please search for ready solutions and try to adapt them for your needs first. Feel free to come back when you've got a specific issue you cannot resolve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of doing this is a single query it may be easier to create a stored procedure.  One method would be to create a table which you then update, or create a temporary table that you simply output.  Here is something to get you on the right track...

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE
 (ID INT, 
  TheDate DATETIME, 
  PartyName VARCHAR(50), 
  Amount INT, 
  RunningTotal INT etc...)

DECLARE @ID INT, @Amount INT, @RunningTotal INT

INSERT INTO @Table
SELECT....  --here you can insert all the fields except for the RunningTotal

DECLARE #cTmp CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR 
SELECT ID, Amount FROM @Table

OPEN #cTmp
FETCH NEXT FROM #cTmp INTO @ID, @Amount

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
  --Process each row
  SET @RunningTotal = @RunningTotal + @Amount

  --Update the table
  UPDATE @Table SET RunningTotal = @RunningTotal WHERE ID=@ID

  FETCH NEXT FROM #cTmp INTO @ID, @Amount
END
CLOSE #cTmp
DEALLOCATE #cTmp

SELECT * FROM @Table
```